# How to setup dynamic resizing on my existing documentdb cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-documentdb

I have an existing DocumentDB cluster on AWS and I notice that when I deleted 7 million documents from a collection that the '`storageSize`' reported by '`stats()`' remained the same.  I thought that [dynamic resizing](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/06/amazon-documentdb-mongodb-dynamic-resizing-storage/) is now standard, but it doesn't appear to be working on my instance.

I searched AWS DocumentDB [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/documentdb/latest/developerguide/how-it-works.html#how-it-works.storage) but can not find anything about dynamic resizing.

How do I get more information about dynamic resizing?

Answer (score 1):

Storage size is reduced when you drop namespaces, i.e. databases, collections or indexes. Storage use does not decrease when deleting individual documents. Dynamic resizing works for DocumentDB versions 4.0 and 5.0, not for 3.6.